# Create signal from input in gtk3, python, raspberry pi

Tags: python, user-interface, raspberry-pi, gtk3, glade

I have made a gui program on raspberry pi3 and I want to get a signal from input (gpio) to execute some commands like when a button is pressed a signal is generated.
I want to get this signal but from an input.
the code is

```
import time
import gi
import  RPi.GPIO as GPIO
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

class gui:
  inputValue = GPIO.input(18)
  if inputValue == True:
    self.label.set_text("There is input")
  def on_window1_destroy(self, object, data=None):
    print( "quit with cancel")
    Gtk.main_quit()
  def on_okButton_clicked(self,button,data=None):
    self.label.set_text("Waiting for input")
  def __init__(self):
    self.gladefile = "2.glade"
    self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
    self.builder.add_from_file(self.gladefile)
    self.builder.connect_signals(self)
    self.window = self.builder.get_object("window1")
    self.label = self.builder.get_object("Label")
    self.label.set_text("Hello")
    self.window.show_all()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main = gui()
  Gtk.main()
```

The input is taken only at the beginning of the execution and when I use a loop the window freezes.
please help me.
thanks.

Comment: What code do you have? Have you read tutorials like [here](http://raspi.tv/2013/how-to-use-interrupts-with-python-on-the-raspberry-pi-and-rpi-gpio-part-2)?

Comment: Code is added.The input is taken only at the beginning of the execution and when I use a loop the window freezes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it by editing the code as bellow:

```
import time
import gi
import  RPi.GPIO as GPIO
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

class gui:

  def pin_callback (self, channel):
    print ('pressed')
    self.label.set_text("INput")

  def on_window1_destroy(self, object, data=None):
    print( "quit with cancel")
    Gtk.main_quit()
  def on_okButton_clicked(self,button,data=None):
    self.label.set_text("Waiting for input")
  def __init__(self):
    self.gladefile = "m.glade"
    self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
    self.builder.add_from_file(self.gladefile)
    self.builder.connect_signals(self)
    self.window = self.builder.get_object("window1")
    self.label = self.builder.get_object("Label")
    self.label.set_text("Hello")
    self.window.show_all()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main = gui()
  GPIO.add_event_detect(18, GPIO.BOTH, callback=main.pin_callback)
  Gtk.main()
```

Thank you very much, theGtknerd.

Comment: There's nothing in there preventing whatever can happen when you call Gtk functionality from another thread than the one the mainloop is running in.  This may appear to work, but is broken.

Answer (score 1):

My PI is stashed away in a box. This code is not tested, only off the top of my head. Tell me if it works.

```
import time
import gi
import  RPi.GPIO as GPIO
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

class gui:
  def pin_callback (self, channel):
    print ('pressed')
  def on_window1_destroy(self, object, data=None):
    print( "quit with cancel")
    Gtk.main_quit()
  def on_okButton_clicked(self,button,data=None):
    self.label.set_text("Waiting for input")
  def __init__(self):
    self.gladefile = "2.glade"
    self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
    self.builder.add_from_file(self.gladefile)
    self.builder.connect_signals(self)
    self.window = self.builder.get_object("window1")
    self.label = self.builder.get_object("Label")
    self.label.set_text("Hello")
    self.window.show_all()
    GPIO.add_event_detect(18, GPIO.BOTH, callback=self.pin_callback)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main = gui()
  Gtk.main()
```

Comment: This is the result.Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/m.py", line 10, in <module>
    class gui:
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/m.py", line 13, in gui
    GPIO.add_event_detect(18, GPIO.BOTH, callback=self.pin_callback)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: @MohamedGad The edited version should now be another way to do this.